# how to bind two class in Laravel Service Container

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have a class named `Cat.php` as following:

```
class Cat {
    public $animal;
    public function __construct(MyInterface $animal)
    {
        $this->animal = $animal;
    }
}
```

and I have an other class named `Animal.php` and it implement ‍‍`MyInterface‍`

I need to use `Cat` class with `Animal` class entrance

It's worked for me:

```
app()->bind('Cat', function (){
    return new Cat(new Animal());
});
```

but I do not like it. 
So I tested the following code:

```
app()->bind('Cat', Cat::class);
```

and use class as following :

```
$cat = app()->make('Cat');
```

but my problem is this code can not find Animal class.
How do I introduce animal class to cat class?

Answer (score -1):

Could you try,

```
app()->makeWith('Cat', new Animal())
```